# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip

I'm beginner in Django and I want to use MySQL with but when I try to run server with `python manage.py runserver` I get "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.".
**Mac OS**;
**Python version** : 3.7.6;
**Django version** : (3, 0, 2, 'final', 0).
thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to upgrade the `mysqlclient`, so with `pip3 install -U mysqlclient`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did `pip3 install -U mysqlclient` and I get `Requirement already up-to-date: mysqlclient in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4.6)` but the error is always the same.